# Python twisted irc - server password on login

Tags: python, twisted, irc

I'm trying to create a simple IRC bot in Python using Twisted. I've come pretty far but have encountered a problem when I need to provide the password to enter the server.

I know how to implement a password for joining a specific channel but I have no clue how to provide a username and password upon joining the IRC server itself.

The reason I need to provide a password is that I want the bot to be bouncer-compatible (ZNC).

(Excuse the lousy indentation)

**This is what I've tried so far**

```
import re
import urllib2
import random
import time
import sys
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.internet import protocol

def is_valid_int(num):
"""Check if input is valid integer"""
    try:
        int(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def isAdmin(user):
    with open("admins.txt", "r") as adminfile:
        lines = adminfile.readlines()
        if not lines:
            return False

        if user in lines:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Bot(irc.IRCClient):
    def _get_nickname(self):
        return self.factory.nickname

    nickname = property(_get_nickname)

    # @Event Signed on
    def signedOn(self):
        self.join(self.factory.channel)
        print "Signed on as %s." % (self.nickname,)

    # @Event Joined
    def joined(self, channel):
        print "Joined %s." % (channel,)

    # @Event Privmsg
    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        if msg == "!time":
            msg = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
            self.msg(channel, msg)

        # Google searhc
        elif msg.startswith("!google"):
            msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
            msg = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + msg[1]
            self.msg(channel, msg)

        # Quit connection
        elif msg.startswith("!quit"):
        self.quit("byebye")

        # Set nickname
        elif msg.startswith("!nick"):
        msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
        newNick = msg[1]
        self.setNick(newNick)

        # Invite to channel
        elif msg.startswith("!invite"):
        msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
        channel = msg[1]
        self.join(channel)
        print("Joined channel %s" % channel)

        # Leave channel
        elif msg.startswith("!leave"):
        msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
        channel = msg[1]
        self.leave(channel)
        print("Left channel %s" % (channel))

        # Dice roll
        elif msg.startswith("!roll"):
            user = user.split("!", 2)
            nick = user[0]
            self.msg(channel, nick + " rolled a " + str(random.randint(0,100)))
            print("Rolled dice...")

        # Op user
        elif msg.startswith("!op") or msg.startswith("!+o"):
            msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
            nick = msg[1]

            if isAdmin(nick) == True:
                self.mode(channel, True, "o", user=nick)
            else:
                self.msg(channel, "Not registered as admin, contact bot owner.")

        # Deop user
        elif msg.startswith("!deop") or msg.startswith("!-o"):
            msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
            nick = msg[1]

            if isAdmin(nick) == True:
                self.mode(channel, False, "o", user=nick)
            else:
                self.msg(channel, "Not registered as admin, contact bot owner.")

        # Voice user
        elif msg.startswith("!voice") or msg.startswith("!+v"):
            msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
            nick = msg[1]

            if isAdmin(nick) == True:
                self.mode(channel, True, "v", user=nick)
            else:
                self.msg(channel, "Not registered as admin, contact bot owner.")

        # Devoice user
        elif msg.startswith("!devoice") or msg.startswith("!-v"):
            msg = msg.split(" ", 2)
            nick = msg[1]

            if isAdmin(nick) == True:
                self.mode(channel, False, "v", user=nick)
            else:
                self.msg(channel, "Not registered as admin, contact bot owner.")



class BotFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
"""Factory for our bot"""
protocol = Bot

    def __init__(self, channel, nickname="IRCBot", username=None, password=None):
        self.channel = channel
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Lost connection: (%s)" % (reason,)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Could not connect: %s" % (reason,)


if __name__ == "__main__":
reactor.connectTCP("my.irc.server.com", 6667, BotFactory("Channel", "IRCBot", "Name", "Password"))
reactor.run()
```

I can't find anything in the Twisted documentation about server passwords, only channel passwords. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html

I notice the attribute `password`, with the description:

```
password =
    Password used to log on to the server. May be None.
```

It seems to me you can set password attribute on your `Bot` class, thus

```
class Bot(irc.IRCClient):
    def _get_nickname(self):
        return self.factory.nickname

    nickname = property(_get_nickname)
    password = "PASSWORD"

    ...
```

Does it makes sense? And does it work?

All the best :)

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. :( I don't get any error message, the connection just times out or something.

Comment: It should work! Just checked out the source code of IRCClient

https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py#L2414

Checkout the function `register` and `connectionMade`. As I see it the implementation is in accordence with rfc1459 (IRC,  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459.html) section 4.1 describing Connection Registration, so i think your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: What does your IRC server log say?

Comment: I don't have access to the server log so I can't check that... Unfortunately I didn't figure it out :/ It doesn't throw any exceptions, I just get this: "Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly." after 5 or so minutes

Comment: I should add that I'm still a beginner at Python, this is one of my first "larger" projects.

Comment: I just read you code and some stuff are going very wrong, you dont seem to understand the relation between protocols and protocol factories. It feels like you are a little in over your head. I wrote a little script for you, please adjustthe variables with CAPITALS to your needs and run it. Please post the output. Then i will try to help you further. 

https://gist.github.com/brunsgaard/6c9d3f2c6dd344180430

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54366/discussion-between-brunsgaard-and-em-bq).